# subset of L2 is precompact

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to prove that subset X of space $\mathcal L^2(a,b)$ is precompact if and only if

$\forall \varepsilon>0$  $\exists \delta = \delta(\varepsilon)>0$ that $\forall$ $h, |h|<\delta$ and $x \in X$

$\int_a^b |x(t+h)-x(t)|^2 dt < \varepsilon$

how it can be done? i suppose it's true, anyways i also can't prove why it's not

Comment: I do not see any question.

Comment: sry, how it can be done?

Comment: @user159517: No, it isn't.

Comment: @KEK_SAS What work have you done so far to try and prove that true?